# Shifting BigInteger of Java by long variable

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, biginteger

I know there are methods `shiftLeft(int n)` and `shiftRight(int n)` for `BigInteger` class which only takes int type as an argument but I have to shift it by a `long` variable. Is there any method to do it?

Comment: are you sure you want to do it? is your long number really a number which is outside int range?

Comment: Maybe I'm naive but I think even "just" shifting by Integer.MAX_VALUE is probably a huge undertaking. Please tell me you also need `long` exponents for `pow()`.

Comment: yes the long variable might go up to 10^10 @RamanShrivastava

Comment: What are you using this for? Hopefully there's an alternative approach

Comment: If your values are sparse (have few bits set) you could represent values using a `Set<Long>`, or even a `Set<BigInteger>`. I don't know if there are any libraries out there with an integer class that does something like this.

Comment: @harold to solve a problem in competitive coding website, where i have to divide the final result by power of 2 and the power can be up to 10^10. May be naive approach doesn't work, should try another approach.

Comment: If it's a coding challenge you can be certain that the naive approach isn't what they are expecting. i.e it's a challenge. Is it something like, what are the last 8 digits of 2^(10^10) for example?

Comment: yes you are right @PeterLawrey but at least I learned a new thing today. Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/SEPT15/problems/CODECRCK this is the problem if you want to look into. Don't reveal the logic I am still trying it ;) @PeterLawrey

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BigInteger can only have Integer.MAX_VALUE bits.  Shifting right by more than this will always be zero.  Shift left any value but zero will be an overflow.

From the Javadoc

```
 * BigInteger constructors and operations throw {@code ArithmeticException} when
 * the result is out of the supported range of
 * -2<sup>{@code Integer.MAX_VALUE}</sup> (exclusive) to
 * +2<sup>{@code Integer.MAX_VALUE}</sup> (exclusive).
```

If you need more than 2 billion bits to represent your value, you have a fairly usual problem, BigInteger wasn't designed for.

If you need to do bit manipulation on a very large scale, I suggest having an `BitSet[]`  This will allow up to 2 bn of 2 bn bit sets, more than your addressable memory.

> yes the long variable might go up to 10^10

For each `10^10` bit number you need 1.25 TB of memory.  For this size of data, you may need to store it off heap,  we have a library which persist this much data in a single memory mapping without using much heap, but you need to have this much space free on a single disk at least. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes

Comment: 2 gigs of memory to represent a single integer... huh, yeah, must be unusual

Comment: @Dici 2 bn bits is actually 256 MB, but to do anything with it quickly adds up. a = b + 2 * c, already you have 1 GB. if you did a `a * b` using 1 bn bit numbers it would complete in `O(n^2)` time, assuming the machine ran that long, ;)

Comment: Mmm yeah it's gigs of bits but usually we talk in bytes, true

Comment: `Shifting left by more than this will always be zero. Shift right any value but zero will be an overflow.` Left <-> Right need swapping.

Comment: @biziclop you are right and I should go to bed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`BigInteger` does not support values where `long` shift amounts would be appropriate. I tried

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

and I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range.

Comment: I have a doubt in the above exception. Can BigInteger overflow? if so what is the maximum value it can store?

Comment: @user3901994 it's in the Javadoc, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `2 ^ X` is equal to `10 ^ (X * ln(2) / ln(10))`, we can calculate for `X = 10 ^ 10`:

```
2 ^ (10 ^ 10) = 10 ^ 3,010,299,956.63981195...
              = 10 ^ 3,010,299,956 * 10 ^ 0.63981195...
              = 4.3632686... * 10 ^ 3,010,299,956
```

Meaning 4 followed by more than 3 *billion* more digits.

That's a very large number and will take some doing storing that to full precision.